# RuntimeError: faster_rcnn_fbnetv3a_C4.yaml not available in Model Zoo! in d2go

Tags: python, facebook, model, quantization, detectron

I am trying to run D2GO_Introduction.ipynb [Notebook link](https://github.com/TannerGilbert/Object-Detection-and-Image-Segmentation-with-Detectron2/blob/master/D2Go/D2GO_Introduction.ipynb) file but I am facing some issue with that I am getting that error during getting the model from model zoo ,, "RuntimeError: faster_rcnn_fbnetv3a_C4.yaml not available in Model Zoo"
Here is the snapshot, I have installed everything correctly from the documentation, please consider your feedback.

[snapshot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRW2P.png)

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? Running into the same issue myself